# Background image not appearing, just normal white background

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to set a background image i can then blur but when i try to create a class="background" class it doesnt seem to work and remains white on the background.

I originally had the background image set as the body but it would just blue the whole page when i'd set set blur code.

I also tried doing it as an ID instead of a class

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("HillSide.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#header {
  height: 200px;
  /*Height of the block*/
  line-height: 100px;
  /*centers the text at 100px between 200px*/
  margin-left: 10px;
  /*Makes the block 10px from screen left side*/
  margin-right: 50px;
  /*Makes the block 100px from screen right side*/
}

#BlenkaLogo {
  height: 200px;
  /*Changes the logo height to 200px*/
  display: inline;
  /*Changing to an inline element instead of a block element*/
}

ul {
  min-width: 400px;
  /*The minimum width of the element in total*/
  display: inline;
  /*Make it an inline element*/
  float: right;
  /*change to the right hand side*/
  margin: auto;
  /*Margin as 0/auto*/
}

li {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline;
  /*Make it an inline element*/
  margin-left: 50px;
  /*padding between text*/
}

#header a {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<div id="header">
  <!--header block-->
  <img src="BlenkaLogo.jpeg" id="BlenkaLogo" href="index.html">
  <!--Blenka Logo with link o homepage-->
  <ul>
    <!--List of about and Amazon link-->
    <li>
      <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QC93DV7" rel="nofollow noreferrer" style="text-decoration: none">Buy on Amazon</a>
      <!--Amazon Link-->
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" style="text-decoration: none">About</a>
      <!--About page link-->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect it to create an image on the page at very least, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It happened because your "background" div is empty and there is no styling for height/width. So, it didn't render. 
Put something inside your div/provide dimensions and it will render with the background.

Comment: Okay i've provided dimensions and indeed it works! but now it is on the "top layer", how can i make it the background